# How to optimize code that uses Dictionary<string, class>

Tags: c#, optimization, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
// Dictionary which I want to optimize
Dictionary<string, MyClass> myDict;
//
Dictionary<int, KKSKey> kksKeyList;

...    
...
...

// Classes
[Serializable]
public class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{
    Dictionary<int, DebugValue> myDebugValues;    
    ...
    ...
    ...
}

//
[Serializable]
public class DebugValue
{
    public int ValueType {get;set;}
    public double Value {get;set;}
    ...
    ...
    ...
}

public class KKSKey
{
    public string KKS { set; get; }
    public string Variable { set; get; }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

The reason I used dictionaries everywhere is because I need to access the lists by a key.

I have the following lines in a `for` loop that runs just over 550,000 (yes!) times. `myDict` has about 10,000 items and `kksKeyList` has over 550,000 items.

Each of the following lines runs for `i = 0 to 550,000`:

```
myDict[kksKeyList[i].KKS].myDebugValues[i].ValueType = DOUBLE;
myDict[kksKeyList[i].KKS].myDebugValues[i].Value = tempdouble;
```

Basically, the above lines are filling up the dictionary items with raw data received over TCP. Each one of the above line takes about 90-100 milliseconds per `for` loop (550,000 times). This is not acceptable for my application. It must complete one of above lines within 50 milliseconds. Can anyone suggest how to optimize the performance of above operation? I am open to any suggestions, even if it means redefining the related classes if necessary.

Comment: What are `DOUBLE` and `tempdouble`? Are they constant?

Comment: from the few that we see here I would say no, I cannot sugguest another approach (you could try to extrakt the multiple accesses to the dicts into seperate variables but I think the compiler will do so anyway if you let it optimize your code) - asside from this the only think I could think of is to parallize this (should be easy) or to try and shrink your 550.000 count somehow

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to understand the problem you're trying to overcome with the solution provided in your question. Perhaps you can clarify exactly what you need with simpler names than KKSkey

Comment: @BigYellowCactus, DOUBLE is an ENUM and tempdouble is a local double variable that holds the value received on TCP channel.

Comment: @Polity, the problem with the approach that I am using as above is that this code takes about 90-100 ms/line to complete 550,000 iterations. I want to reduce that time to about 50 ms.

Comment: @Carsten König, I have that though (of parallizing this code) at the back of my mind.

Comment: @silverspoon - I know but i think this question needs thinking outside the box. For that, i need to know exactly what your trying to do. Right now with the current example code/naming its a bit hard to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
string kks = kksKeyList[i].KKS;
myDict[kks].myDebugValues[i].ValueType = DOUBLE;
myDict[kks].myDebugValues[i].Value = tempdouble;
```

or maybe:

```
myDict[kksKeyList[i].KKS] = new DebugValue(DOUBLE, tempdouble)
```

If it suits your constructor...

Comment: I think that only reduces it from 6 Dictionary hits to 5

Comment: or `DebugValue v = myDict[kksKeyList[i].KKS]` and `v.ValueType=DOUBLE`, `v.Value = tempdouble` if the constructor form is no good to you.

Comment: has someone checked this? IMHO the complier will see this easy optimization anyhow

Comment: @Urik, your solution helped me. It definitely reduced the timing by about 25-30ms/line for 2 lines where I was having problem. Another thing that I changed was setting "myDict[kksKeyList[i].KKS].myDebugValues[i].ValueType" in the constructor instead of setting it in this big for loop. These 2 things worked quite well for me. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You timings are way too slow.  A millisecond is an eternity with this kind of problem, and 550,000 elements in a dictionary is chicken feed.  My first thought is that your problem is with your data source, not your Dictionaries; a millisecond is a lot more time in network communications.

*If* the dictionaries *are* the problem, take a look at your memory.  Dictionaries are hash tables which are, essentially, arrays.  When you create one, it starts out with an array of a certain size.  As it expands, it allocates a new, larger array and throws away the old one.  If your 550,000 element dictionary starts with room for 10 elements, it will leave "available" memory littered with big chunks of memory that can't be used because the next allocation is bigger still.  The GC will work hard to rearrange memory and make all these blocks contiguous, and if it's doing this while you're running your two problem statements, it will slow things down.  To fix this, first allocate space for 550,000 entries when you create the dictionary.  That will probably be sufficient, but also call `GC.Collect()`.  This will get the GC work out of the way in one go and give you clean timings when you want them.

Another memory problem may be `myDebugValues`.  You've got one of these for each of the 550,000 entries in `myDict`.  Just as you wanted myDict to be large right from the start, these need to be small.  I might even suggest a ListDictionary or a HybridDictionary ([System.Collections.Specialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized)).

The key thing with memory is to use only real memory rather than virtual; once your machine starts paging you're in trouble.  And keep your GC happy.

Hope this helps, or else that someone else comes up with a better answer.  (I liked Urik's, but the optimizers are probably doing that already.)

Comment: your comment looks interesting. I will give it a try. Thanks!